# 8 Letter Word with 5 Vowels

Tags: combinatorics

How many 8 letter words can be formed using 5 distinct vowels and rest distinct consonants.

Approach 1:

Number of ways to choose vowels: $\binom{5}{5}$

Number of ways to choose places for five vowels: $\binom{8}{5}$

Number of ways to choose consonants: $\binom{21}{3}$

Number of ways to choose places for three consonants: $\binom{3}{3}$

Number of ways to permutate this collection: $8!$

Final answer:
$$
\binom{5}{5}\binom{8}{5}\binom{21}{3}\binom{3}{3}8!
$$

Approach 2:

Number of ways to choose vowels: $\binom{5}{5}$

Number of ways to choose places for five vowels: $\binom{8}{5}$

Number of ways to permutate the vowels: $5!$

Number of ways to choose consonants: $\binom{21}{3}$

Number of ways to choose places for three consonants: $\binom{3}{3}$

Number of ways to permutate consonants: $3!$

Final answer:
$$
\binom{5}{5}\binom{8}{5}5!\binom{21}{3}\binom{3}{3}3!
$$

Which approach is correct? And what are the fundamental differences between both the approaches?

Edit:

As pointed by @true blue anil I believe Approach 1 is wrong. And it should be replace by:
$$
\binom{5}{5}\binom{21}{3}8!
$$

Comment: Are the vowels required to be different?

Comment: Yes. Making edits to show this in question.

Comment: Not only vowels, are all letters to be distinct ?

Comment: Yes. They are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach is correct.
In the first approach, you choose places for vowels and consonants, but then permute all the $8$ letters !

Actually, if you want to use $8!$, you get a simpler formula,

[choose vowels]$\times$[choose consonants]$\times 8!$

Comment: I have edited my question to incorporate this. I have wrongly calculated approach 1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome !$\;\;$ :)